# Autotools: Find out how the configure script was called

Tags: gnu, autotools, autoconf

I have a rather large component, that is built with GNU autotools. Assuming that the configuration step was already done by somebody (by the build server, in this case), can I somehow find out afterwards, how exactly the `./configure` script was called? I mean, with which options?

Thanks, Georg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah found it. It's in the beginning of `config.log`. Was just too simple for me...

Comment: Also `./config.status --version` will show the arguments.